# jQuery - how to access variable from outside of the form

Tags: jquery

Following example:

```
var ClickedTab = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);

$('#loaderDiv').load(TrimedClickedTab + '.html', function() {

    if (ClickedTab == 'quick-form') {

         console.log(' Quick FOR<');

    }
});
```

Currently  `ClickedTab` inside if statement will be undefined, how to access this variable from inside of the function withou changing the syntax?

Comment: where do you define TrimedClickedTab ? Maybe you meant TrimmedClickedTab and it's just a typo? :)

Comment: @Andy - sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could do is to use data() to save your info so that you can get it back later

```
var ClickedTab = $(this).attr("href").substring(1);
//save your data to use it later
$('#yourform').data('ClickedTab', ClickedTab );

$('#loaderDiv').load(TrimedClickedTab + '.html', function() {

    if ($('#yourform').data('ClickedTab') == 'quick-form') {

         console.log(' Quick FOR<');

    }
});
```

But in your case you should be able to see it just as is as you can see from thois fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5QEfm/

So the error must be somewhere else

Comment: In my example still ` ClickedTab is undefined`

Comment: but are you sure that it is defined before the load call?If you console.log() it do you see something?